# What's the differences between these two types of application on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

The traditional application:

[image]

And the applications listed here:

[image]

What're the differences between them? When I install an application, how can I know it goes to which category? Thanks.

Comment: The applications obtained via Microsoft store are not listed in Programs and Features.

Comment: The old one brings the list from some more registry places than the new one. Can’t remember exactly where they are.

Comment: @КонстантинВан I had compared both lists on my station, and had not found any application which is listed in `Programs and Features` and is not listed in `Apps & features`. Does you have such app? What is it?

Comment: @Akina I found them when I was programmatically uninstalling Adobe programs, removing some registry items at a place. They disappeared from the _Apps & Features_, while remained in the _Programs and Features_. After removing some more items at another path, they finally disappeared from both.

Comment: @КонстантинВан *After removing some more items at another path, they finally disappeared from both.* Looks like caching effect... as I remember `Programs and Features` looks `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` only.

Comment: And it seems that `Apps & features` scans MrtCache additionally.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is probably that the one in the settings menu allows you to manage default Windows 10 apps and Microsoft Store apps as well as apps you installed.